# RestKit: POST request using named route

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am trying to use RestKit for an iOS application. So far, it works great. I have set up my routes with the router and can send requests using them.

I have been searching this for hours and can't find how to send a post request for a named route. I tried to use `getObjectsAtPathForRouteNamed:object:parameters:success:failure`, but it can only be used for `GET` requests. I know that I can send a `POST` request by creating a route mapped to a class using `postObject:path:parameters:success:failure:`, but I already have another route with `POST` for this class.

So the question is: Is there a way to send `POST` request using RestKit using named routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RestKit does assume that you only have one destination (route) for posting any one type of class. This is on a per-object-manager basis. So, if you want multiple different routes for a class they each need to be managed by a different instance of `RKObjectManager`.

Comment: In the Github readme Routing section, the example they give is "[manager.router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithName:@"thumbs_down_review" resourcePathPattern:@"/reviews/:reviewID/thumbs_down" method:RKRequestMethodPOST]];". Surely the app would also need a post route for a review.. to create it? So, if you can only have 1 post route per class, why would the above example make sense?

Comment: @Marc, you can have multiple named routes, each of which is used for the same class. What you can't have is multiple (anonymous) routes where you only specify the class (otherwise, which one should be chosen when you provide an instance of that class...)